# JQuery web service authorization

Tags: javascript, jquery

My client has a web service API which I must connect to first with a payload of username and password to get SecurityToken, then use this SecurityToken as part of the header sent for all following API calls, so I was wondering how I can do this using JQuery $.ajax method. Any example is highly appreciated.

Here is what I've tried so far in authenticating but it is always returning error in response so I am not sure if it is correct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $.ajax
      ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://portal.domainname.com/auth",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: '{"Login : admin@email.com", "Password : test"}',
        success: function (){
            alert('Success'); 
        },
        error: function(xhr, error){
            console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
        } 
    });

});
```

Problem with the above code is that it always return 200 OK status but token is never returned in response

Comment: Have you tried anything? There's plenty of `$.ajax()` tutorials out there. This seems very straight forward

Comment: @tymeJV Yes sorry for not adding it in the original question. I've just added it above. But I am always getting 200 OK status with nothing in response, in other words the token is never returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to send `data` as an object, rather than a string, since string [implies](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it's a query string:

`data: JSON.stringify({ 
    Login: "admin@email.com", 
    Password : "test"
}),`

Also, if you are getting a 200, then it means the response was successful (and you should use the `success` callback), however all your logic is in the `error` callback instead.  You probably want:

```
success: function(data) {
    // Do something with data
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code but I am getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @MChan Yeah I copied and pasted the string you had, but it was formatting the key-value pairs incorrectly. :P  Fixed it now.

Comment: thanks for updating the answer, it is not giving an error now :) BUT I still can't get a token back. One thing my client added to me is that the login info must be sent in JSON format. So it is like when you go for example to Google Chrome and test, instead of sending the login as params, you must click on Row tab, paste the login data and json and send. So I was wondering how I can make sure that data is posted as json in my code (taking in consideration that I've already set the datatype to json)? Thanks

Comment: @MChan Updated.  Just wrap the data in a `JSON.stringify()` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sincerely appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

For me the JSON that you are sending is not valid json:

```
data: '{"Login : admin@email.com", "Password : test"}',
```

it should be

```
data: '{"Login" : "admin@email.com", "Password" : "test"}',
```